# Html elements not registering when updates uploaded to cPanel

Tags: html, css, sass, cpanel, file-manager

I am using cPanel on BlueHost to make a website for a client. I have uploaded my files to the public.html folder and everything is live and looks good. But when I make changes and upload the files again.. some of the new html elements that I have added dont show up on mobile. They show up on desktop so I know its working and registering but idk why it wont show up on my phone. Any ideas? Im not sure if its a cPanel problem. I dont think its a Sass problem either. Do mobile devices take longer to recognize changes on a hosted site? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: did you try clearing your mobile browser cache? or try using incognito. Also, you should really start using a different method for uploading files (eg. FTP client, GIT, etc. )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for joining the community. I'll be glad to help you or find a solution.

If you are just copying and pasting the files from your computer to the cpannel keep in mind that you need to change the path of some files in order for them to grab the style or any external sheet, I had a similar problem when uploading my website